# Looking for a more detailed answer on why Allah created us

Tags: allah, ibadah, theology

Disclaimer: I am a true muslim, but asking to get the right answer.

So, if we accept that Allah has created us to worship him, it doesn’t seem too convincing from a high level. Let’s say Allah gave us free will and that’s why he wants to see who worships him, and who doesn’t. But if that’s the case, why did he need it at all?

If the answer to this is that he wanted to “test” us, it brings everyone back to square one. If “testing” us was the case, why not just test if we act good to each other? Why also imply the rule of worshipping him?

Initially Allah created angels, then other beings (i might be unaware) and finally us. If he wasn’t fulfilled with the other beings’ worship, did this spark his interest to create humans? If that’s so, doesn’t that mean that Allah is provoked by a motive, which he, by definition, shouldn’t be?

Some people tend to give the example of a teacher and his students, where the teacher would test his students to see who is doing better. But this us a very vague comparison given that the “Job” of a teacher is to test. The society expects a teacher to test and created/filter the best students. But Allah has no such surrounding to provoke him this way. Then why…?

So if anyone could answer this in the most logical way, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> **Quran 51: 56-58**
>
> I created the jinn and humans for nothing else but that they may serve
> Me; I desire from them no provision, nor do I want them to feed
> Me. Surely Allah is the Bestower of all provision, the Lord of
> all power, the Strong.

There are two deep questions hidden inside the  the question **"why Allah created us?"**

- What were Allah's reasons for creating human beings on earth? .
- What Allah expects from us? .

**The verses I have posted above gives us answer for the second question.**

What is expected from us? Just worship Allah. Think about it. It is a simple and single answer which covers everyone. The rich and the poor; the healthy and the ill; the powerful and the weak — all are given the same target. This answer gives lots of comfort for believers when things are not going right.

**As far as I know, the answer to the first question is not given directly in Quran.**

There are some hints. However those hints are part of the Quran which is highly allegorical.

> **Quran 2:30-31**

> Just recall the time when your Lord said to the angels, "I am going to appoint a vicegerent on the Earth." They humbly enquired, **"Are you going to appoint such a one as will cause disorder and shed blood on the Earth? We are already engaged in hymning Your praise, and hallowing Your name".** Allah replied, **"I know what you do not know."**...

This is the question that you are asking. What is the reasoning for creating humans when we cause so much bloodshed? If worship is the only reason, the angels are better at worship than us!

The answer from Allah is, "I know what you don't know". What this means is **(1) that the reason has not been revealed (2) however a reason does exist!**

I will not try to present my half formed ideas and theories about these verses as per warning given by Quran 3:7. (Check it yourself)

And we pray to Allah as per the words of **Quran 3:8**

> ...'Our Lord! Do not let our hearts swerve towards crookedness after You have guided us to the right way, and. bestow upon us Your mercy. Surely You, only You, are the Munificent Giver!

Comment: The part where you mentioned "A reason exists" is what makes this answer more viable. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

It says directly in the Quran that:

> I did not create jinn and humans except to worship Me.
>
> <sup>[Quran 51:56](https://quran.com/51?startingVerse=56)</sup>
>
> I seek no provision from them, nor do I need them to feed Me.
>
> <sup>[Quran 51:57](https://quran.com/51?startingVerse=57)</sup>

To further expand upon Quran 51:56, there is a Hasan Gharib Qudsi hadith, meaning it is not authentic but is used by some scholars in this case to empathize an idea, cited in [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.com/51:56/tafsirs/en-tafisr-ibn-kathir) which demonstrates god's desire to be worshipped.

> “O Son of Adam! Dedicate
> yourself to worshipping Me (tafarrugh), and I will fill your chest with riches and
> make your poverty dissipate. Otherwise, I will fill your chest with distractions
> and will not make your poverty dissipate

Classical Islamic scholar Al-Zamakhsharī argues that Quran 51:56 points to the purpose for which human beings were created, even if most of them do not fulfill this function (worshipping Allah).

In the tafsir Maʿālim al-tanzīl, according to a saying attributed to Ibn ʿAbbās, save to worship Me means
“save to know Me”. Viewed in this light, Quran 51:56 follows upon the declaration
in Quran 51:49 that all things were created so that people could remember or recollect,
“since God created the cosmos only for knowledge of Him” (Futūḥāt, IV
221.20).

Allah **didn't** create us because he needs us in anyway. He is the most powerful and is self-sustaining as expressed in Quran 51:57.

And from a more philosophical perspective, I recommend you watch this short youtube video featuring Seyyed Hossein Nasr: [Seyyed Hossein Nasr - Why does evil exist?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLZ6zrPy6oo) Which touches upon the reason why god created us.

- The divine infinitude of god must include the possibility of manifestation, of creation, of self-disclosure.

So for us humans, this life is a test, but for god, he wanted to be worshipped, wanted to be known.

Source: [The Study Quran](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran_202111/page/n2920/mode/1up)

Comment: Please read my question again. You are just referring to the "ibadah" part which is not what i am looking for.

Comment: You're asking what motivated god to create us, to test us. What was his purpose in creating us in the first place. Our purpose as human beings is to worship him. His purpose for creating us It's because he wanted to be known as I explained in my answer.